# How to get field's class type of back bean with converter in jsf?

Tags: jsf-2

I have custom number converter like this:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "myConverter")
public class MyConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        //get property type of back bean
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        // do something
        return null;
    }

}
```

If I could get the type of the backbean's field, I would not have to create a converter for each subclass of `Number`. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: JSF has build-in comverters for `Numbers` (and its subclasses afaik... ) But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758370/get-managed-bean-and-type-bound-to-value-attribute might help

Comment: Yes, it is what I want. Thank you very much !